# How to Write Typescript d.ts FIle to Extend @types/d3

Tags: typescript, d3.js, type-definition

I'm search on google and successfully extend d3js selection with the following ts code:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
d3.selection.prototype.popover = function() {};
```

And then use it from another ts file like:

```
(d3.select("svg").selectAll(".node") as any).popover();
```

This works, but I dno't like "`any`" here and want to extend the `@types/d3` definition (I alread install @types/d3).
I create a d3.extend.d.ts along the function code ts file, and write:

```
/// <referencepath="../../node_modules/@types/d3-selection/index.d.ts">
declare module "d3-selection"{
   export interface Selection<GElement extends BaseType, Datum, PElement extends BaseType, PDatum>{
      popover();
   }
}
```

But this seems doesn't work, if I remove `any` from the calling code, ts compiler will get error.

Updated: I updated my code based on the answer to make it to be the final work version

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration merging needs to use the name of the module - `d3-selection` - in which `Selection` is declared. Like this:

```
declare module "d3-selection" {
  export interface Selection<
    GElement extends BaseType,
    Datum,
    PElement extends BaseType,
    PDatum
  > {
    popover(): void;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to follow this to do something similar ... I want to add hide() and show() methods to d3.Selection ... but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Do I need to add two files?  e.g.  hide.d.ts and hide.ts  where hide.d.ts is the interface (for merging with the real d3-selection)?

Comment: Maybe you should your comment as a question that references this one?